# Check for dtoverlay=w1-gpio error despite the line being present in /boot/config.txt

Tags: raspi-config, ds18b20

I am trying to use a DS18B20 temperature sensor in a thermostat project but a few days ago when I shut down my rpi4(B) and restarted it the next day, without any change in code or the circuit I received this error.

```
Please check cabling and check your /boot/config.txt for dtoverlay=w1-gpio
```

I have since tried disabling and enabling the 1-wire interface from the preferences multiple times, I have manually changed config.txt from the console and I have rebuilt the connections to make sure nothing is wrong with the pins or my connections.
One interesting thing was that while fixing it I decided to remove this line entirely and rebooted.

```
dtoverlay=w1-gpio
```

This would give a new error, however, not one that prompted to check this line in config.txt
Following this I re-added that line and rebooted and the program worked for a few seconds after which it stated that the sensor was not ready.
Here's the simple code I found to use the sensor:

```
import time
from w1thermsensor import W1ThermSensor
sensor=W1ThermSensor()
while True:
temperature=sensor.get_temperature()
print("temp = %s" %temperature)
time.sleep(1)
```

Having spent enough time trying to look for solutions online, I can't seem to find anyone going through this issue where the line

```
dtoverlay=w1-gpio
```

or

```
dtoverlay=w1-gpio,gpiopin=4
```

is present but completely overlooked by the raspi and instead just throws the error like it doesn't exist.

Comment: If it worked before just restore from your backup.

Comment: @Milliways how does one backup and restore cabling  ... it's interesting that the OP has concentrated on solely software, which he states "has not changed" ... the error clearly starts with "Please check cabling ...." but the OP has done nothing at all to check the cabling, check the sensor. poor cabling (no idea how OP has attached the sensor) very easily can "change" just by moving a device, you know, like to plug in a power cable

Comment: @Bravo "but a few days ago when I shut down my rpi4" … "without any change in code or the circuit". The OP has no idea whether anything has changed, but a prudent person would eliminate the most likely cause. I don't know why so many beginners even shut down - my Pi run for years without shutdown.

Comment: @Milliways - if you run your pi "for years without shutdown" - I take it you only shutdown when there's a new major release of Raspbian/Rapberry Pi OS/Noobs ... lol, sorry, I'm kidding about Noobs!!